# Eloquent inverse relationships execute useless query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a standard one-to-many relationship with inverse method:

```
class Place 
{
  public function hotels()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Hotel');
  }
}

class Hotel 
{
  public function place()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Place');
  }
}
```

Everything works fine.

In my controller I need to show a list of the hotels each in one box so I created something similar to this:

```
//place.blade
<h1>{{ $place->name }}</h1>
@foreach($place->hotels as $hotel)
  @include('partials.hotels-box', ['hotel' => $hotel])
@endforeach

//partials/hotels-box.blade
<a href="route('hotelRoute', ['hotel' => $hotel->name, 'place' => $hotel->place->name) }}">
  {{ $hotel->name }}
</a>
@endforeach
```

Everything works fine.

BUT, inside hotels-box.blade, everytime I access place model inside `$hotel`, Eloquent launches a new query (even if the place is always the same and it's the one that triggers the `@foreach`).

The only ideas that came to my mind to avoid this problems are:

- pass `$place` to the partials and use it instead of `$hotel->place`
- manually set `$hotel->place` in controller using a loop

but I don't like them.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `$place` model along with `$hotel` to your partial view. Then instead of using inverse relationship to get a place's name you can simply get it by `$place->name`.

Or if for some reason you don't like doing that, you can also eager load the inverse relationship in your query:

```
$places = Place::with('hotels', 'hotels.place')->get();
```

Comment: It works, but in this way Eloquent triggers 3 query, one for places, one for hotels (where in....) one again for the place.
And also the instances of Place inside into Hotels is a "new instance".

Comment: That's how eager loading work. Without eager loading you would have a single query for each `$hotel->place` call, which for 1000 hotels in a place means 1000 queries. But with eager loading you reduce that to 3 queries.

Comment: Also, don't worry about having "new instances" for each place inside hotels. Objects are very cheap memory wise. Again, I think the best solution is to pass `$place` to your partial view which solves all your problems.

Comment: This situation is a common pattern. I use relationship between models to avoid this kind of solution.

Comment: Why do you need to derive `$place` from the relationship when it's already available to you?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get the associated data while fetching a Models value from DB, then every time you access that data will make a query. To get ride of this problem you should get associated data while fetching from the db.

For example, When you write:

```
 $palce = Place::all();
```

It will query only to fetch all row the `places` table. Point to be noted, no associated `hotel` will be fetched by this query. 
Then if you write,

```
$hotels = $place->hotels;
```

Another query will be made to the db just to fetch all row of `hotels` table associated with that `$place`. 
Then if write something like:

```
foreach($palce->hotels as $hotel){
   $palce = $hotel->place;
}
```

Then, inside the `foreach` loop every time it iterate, a new `JOIN` query will be made to get associated `place` with the `hotels`.

**Solution 1:** 
You can load your all required data while doing the first query like this:

```
$places = Place::with('hotels', 'hotels.place')->get();
```

But the problem with this solution is, you are getting `hotels by place`, then you getting the same `place by hotels`. Unnecessary `join` query as you already have the `place`, no need to get `place by hotels` again.

**Solution 2(better):**

```
$places = Place::with('hotels')->get();
```

In view, do something like this:

```
@foreach($place->hotels as $hotel)
  @include('partials.hotels-box', ['hotel' => $hotel, 'place' => $place])
@endforeach
```

Then, use `$palce` in `partials.hotels-box`. I think you got my point.

Best of luck.

Comment: As i wrote in previous answer, your second solution in not applicable. I use relationships between models to avoid this kind of solution.

Comment: I see. Then you have to go for the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be running into is an eager loading problem also known as n+1. The hotel model hasn't loaded it's `Place` relation yet so it must execute a new query each time.

The easiest solution seems to be that you could just call `$place->name` instead of `$hotel->place->name` in your partial,  but this would only solve the problem if the partial is only called from the code you've provided. If it's called from somewhere else where `$place` doesn't exist then your going to have to solve the eager loading issue.

You should be able to eager load in your controller like so:

```
$place = Place::with('hotels.place')->get ()
```

Notice the dot notation is used to add a child relation of the relation. So you original html will should work without any changes and we've only added one new query.